# HBase Shell: get a list of the row keys

Tags: hbase

How can I print out only the row keys in a particular HBase table, using the hbase shell? The 'scan' command prints out all columns.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One possible method:

```
count 'table_name', INTERVAL=> 1
```

Comment: There's a performance concern here - we can possibly print billions of rows here depending on what's in the table.